# How Come string theory is based on the fact that a "string", a theoretical dimension, exists?

Tags: string-theory

I See no explanations beyond concise explanations that a "string" is nothing more than a hypothetical, one-dimensional subatomic particle. If so, why imagine that they are "strings" instead of just "subatomic particles", or the such?

I don't understand the idealization behind string theory at all ... adding the fact that strings are coexistent with theoretical physics, that says a lot right there.

String theory just seems, to me at least, like a delving dream in to a complex system to model something already existing and know, just in a different way.

Comment: A "string" is a one-dimensional loop who corresponds to a subatomic particle.

Comment: "The Standard Model is from a technical standpoint incompatible with gravity, and that's why string theory became an active field of theoretical physics." ([Source](http://www.superstringtheory.com/experm/exper2.html).) Also see ["Graviton"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton).

Comment: That is only one perspective on "why string theory became an active field". I think a better answer is "the mathematics behind string theory is rich with content and fields medals."

Answer (score 3):

> String theory just seems, to me at least, like a delving dream in to a complex system to model something already existing and know, just in a different way.

There is the error.  It is not that a different way is sought to describe the same data.

The existing theories, the [weak and electromagnetic standard model + QCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), are described theoretically well and the models used do describe existing data and predict new phenomena to be found, as for example the [Higgs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson) found recently at CERN.

Up till last century  Newtonian mechanics was sufficient together with classical electricity and magnetism to model observations. In the micro world physicists discovered, quantum mechanics was postulated and found to be necessary to model and predict nature at that level. It is understanding and utilizing quantum mechanics that sits behind a great number of 20th century innovations and technology.

BUT as we all know, physics includes gravity and its manifestations. Gravity is described well by Newtonian mechanics as far as our everyday life goes, which was also the case until last century , when we probed the atom and new stuff unexplained by classical electromagnetism emerged. The new stuff for gravity is the observation that General Relativity holds and Newtonian mechanics is a limiting case for small distances and masses.
So Newtonian mechanics breaks down as a model when  approaching both the very  large and the very small.

The frontier that is left is in fitting gravity into the framework of small dimensions and quantum mechanics. It was found that if one postulated that elementary particles were not a point in space but had one dimension, as the string has one dimension more than a point, the mathematics developed can include a quantized gravity and can unify all known forces into one model.

No other theoretical proposal has managed to quantize gravity and also give a mathematical framework where the Standard Model of particle physics could be embedded. It is necessary to be able to embed the group structure of the Standard Model into any unified theory, because the SM is an encapsulation of almost all experimentally measured and defined data. Almost, because there are some indications that there exists physics beyond the SM, and the expectation is that the unified theory will model this and predict further effects as demonstrations of its validity.

String theories do have the necessary group structures to accommodate the SM. The drawback is that string theory is very complicated by higher dimensions than our four, and complicated initial  assumptions that have to be fixed before a model can really encompass all the known data and predict new phenomena.

[Supersymmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) is a symmetry of the elementary particles being sought in new particle manifestations at the LHC. If it is found it will boost the expectation that string theories are the way to a unified theory because supersymmetry also can be accommodated in string models naturally.
It is at the frontier of research.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't sound like you are looking for a technical answer, so how about one motivated by previous discoveries in particle physics? Before we knew about the existence of quarks, there were all kinds of particles around. There wasn't an organizing principle which told us why certain particles had certain charges, for example. But then, Gell-Mann (etc...) postulated the existence of fundamental particles making up protons, neutrons, Kaons, etc - the quarks. We had never seen these things - the reason we guessed at their existence was to explain why the particles have the charges they do (see the Wikipedia article on the [8-fold way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_way_%28physics%29))

Currently, particle physics describes lots of wonderful things, but not dark matter (or dark energy). If string theory exists (that is, if vibrating strings are the fundamental objects, not particles), maybe supersymmetry exists, and maybe it can be used to explain dark matter.

So to respond to your last point - string theory might help describe behavior which IS NOT described by the standard model of particle physics.